# Please validate my solution (conditional Probability)

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, self-learning, independence

I have a conditional probability problem as follows

$\Pr\{x>\gamma,\quad xy+y^2>\gamma\}$

where $x$ and $y$ are i.i.d r.v. After conditioning on r.v. $y$

$=\int_{0}^{\infty} \quad \Pr\{x>\gamma\} \quad\Pr\{x>\frac{\gamma}{z}-z\} \quad f_y(z) \quad dz$

$=\int_{0}^{\infty} \quad (1- F_x(\gamma)) \quad (1-F_x(\frac{\gamma}{z}-z)) \quad f_y(z) \quad dz$

I am not sure if the result in the last equation is correct or not? Am I using the probability conditioning right?

any kind of help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Obviously, if $(X,Y)$ are nonnegative and independent, then $$\Pr\{X>\gamma,\,XY+Y^2>\gamma\}=\int_0^\infty \Pr\{X>\gamma,X>(\gamma/z)-z\} \, f_Y(z) \,dz$$

Comment: Thank you Did, So my answer (i.e. $=\int_{0}^{\infty} \quad F_x(\gamma) \quad F_x(\frac{\gamma}{z}-z) \quad f_y(z) \quad dz$) is correct?

Comment: Completely false, actually, since $$\Pr(X>\gamma,X>(\gamma/z)-z)\ne\Pr(X>\gamma)\Pr(X>(\gamma/z)-z)$$ in general.

Comment: Ahh I see, Thank you for your kind reply. Can you please suggest how should I approach this problem? is is possible to perform conditioning on w.r.t to r.v. $X$?  on $\Pr\{X>\gamma, X>\frac{\gamma}{z}-z\}$

Comment: Well, there exists some $z(\gamma)>0$ such that $\max(\gamma,(\gamma/z)-z)=(\gamma/z)-z$ if $0<z<z(\gamma)$ and $\max(\gamma,(\gamma/z)-z)=\gamma$ for every $z>z(\gamma)$. Surely you can compute $z(\gamma)$ and continue?

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align} &\Pr\{x>\gamma,\quad xy+y^2>\gamma\} \\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty} \Pr\{x>\gamma, x>\frac{\gamma}{z}-z\}  f_y(z) dz \\
&=\int_{0}^\infty Pr(x > \max(\gamma, \frac{\gamma}{z}-z )) f_y(z) \, dz \\
&=\int_0^\infty\left(1- F_x(\max(\gamma, \frac{\gamma}{z}-z)) \right)f_y(z) dz\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply :) The problem now is how to solve $F_x(\max{(\gamma,\frac{\gamma}{z}-z)})$. Lets suppose that that is $x$ in an exponential r.v.